# How to configure post logout redirect uri in ADFS 2018?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, adfs

The user is logged off and the ADFS default logout page shows up, how to redirect to another page after logout and how to configure ADFS post_logout_redirect_uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using asp.net application then inside the WsFederationAuthenticationOptions you will have to set SignOutWreply variable like:

```
new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    SignOutWreply = "URL",
                 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this resolved the issue.